# on refreshing /reloading my page , mui drawer loses it background color

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, material-ui

mui drawer works fine once initial start of the app but when i refresh the page it loses its background color to `#fff`
To manage the open of the drawer i'm using react-redux ,which has initial state as true.
Here is my code

```
 <Drawer open={isSideBarOpen}   className={classes.drawer} variant="persistent"  PaperProps={{classes: {root: classes.drawerpaper,},}} anchor="left">
                <Grid item display={'flex'} justifyContent={'center'} alignItems={'center'}>
                    <img src={Logo} alt=" logo"/>
                    <span style={{ cursor: "pointer" }} onClick={() => { dispatch(closeSideBar({ sideBarState: false }))}}></span>
                </Grid>
                <Grid container my={2} display={'flex'} justifyContent={'center'} alignItems={'center'}>
                    <Grid item display={'flex'} justifyContent={'center'} alignItems={'center'}>
                        <Link to={`/user/profile/${userId}`}>
                            <img style={{ width: "70px",height: "70px",borderRadius: "50%"}} src={image ? image: NoProfile}/>
                        </Link>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
</Drawer
```

my styles

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        display: "flex",
        fontFamily: "Poppins",
    },
    drawer: {
        width: "250px",
        color: "#fff",
        flexShrink: 0,
        backgroundColor: '#01073F'
    },
    drawerpaper: {
        width: "250px",
        color: "#fff",
        backgroundColor: '#01073F'
    },
```

Redux part

```
  const { isSideBarOpen } = useSelector((store) => store?.sidebar)
``
```